# Retrieve data from IndexedDB and display

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am trying to fetch data from IndexedDB and display it on screen. However, for some reason it is not displaying anything on screen. The data is already in IndexedDB and I do not have any errors. It is just not popping up on screen.I am getting the data:

```
var tx = db.transaction('keyval',"readonly");
         var store = tx.objectStore('keyval');
         return store.getAll();


for (message in buses) 
        {
           var el = document.createElement('div');
           var content = document.createTextNode(buses[message]);
           el.appendChild(content);
           document.body.appendChild(el);

            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = el;
        }
```

I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

store.getAll() returns an IDBRequest, not an array. If that doesn't help, post a full example or a link to a jsfiddle.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/getAll